# IntelliJ plugin autocompletion

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, autocomplete, intellij-plugin

I'm making an IntelliJ plugin to support a nodeJS framework.
I'm trying to implement autocompletion feature but don't know how to set autocompletion position on top of the list. First I have other autocompletion (mozilla ect..).

Here is my code :

```
LookupElementBuilder
                .create(completionString)
                .withBoldness(true)
                .withCaseSensitivity(false)
                .withIcon(SailsJSIcons.SailsJS)
                .withPresentableText("\t\t\t" + item)
                .withAutoCompletionPolicy(AutoCompletionPolicy.GIVE_CHANCE_TO_OVERWRITE);
```

I suppose `handleInsert` can help me but can't find how use it

Answer (score 1):

You can set `order="first"` on your `completion.contributor` in the `plugin.xml`. Looks like it will make your contributor be called *before* contributors from other sources, resulting in your suggestions being first:

```xml
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <completion.contributor order="first" language="PHP" implementationClass="org.klesun.deep_assoc_completion.entry.DeepKeysCbtr"/>
```

When your contributor is called first, you can also write the code to decide how to position following suggestions or to exclude some of them altogether using  `CompletionResultSet::runRemainingContributes()` and the `PrioritizedLookupElement::withPriority()` suggested by @peter-gromov:

```java
protected void addCompletions(CompletionParameters parameters, ProcessingContext processingContext, CompletionResultSet result) 
{
    // ... some of your code here ...

    result.runRemainingContributors(parameters, otherSourceResult -> {
        // 2000 is any number - make it smaller than on your suggestion to position this suggestion lower
        result.addElement(PrioritizedLookupElement.withPriority(otherSourceResult.getLookupElement(), 2000));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying explicit high priority for your lookup elements via PrioritizedLookupElement#withPriority.

Comment: I just try but position are the same, they doesn't move at all with PrioritizedLookupElement.withPriority(lookup, LookupValueWithPriority.HIGHER) or HIGH

Comment: Then more information is needed. For example, item weights as printed by DumpLookupElementWeights action (ctrl/command+alt+shift+w when lookup list is open)